# Contact Form 7 get post ID of form page to function

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I would like to send a confirmation email to a dynamic recipient. This is in the functions.php file. The below code works, but when I try to replace the static email with a variable, it has an error. How do I properly query the `post_meta` women_email and dynamically insert it in place of the static gmail address?
Example page: https://www.ohioacc.org/women/sandra-nichols/

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function( $contact_form, $abort, $submission ) {
    $women_email = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'women_email', true); 
    //$dynamic_email = $women_email;         THIS DOES NOT WORK
    $dynamic_email = "myemail@gmail.com";  //THIS WORKS 
    $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
    $properties['mail']['recipient'] = $dynamic_email;
    $contact_form->set_properties($properties);  
    return $contact_form; 
  }
  add_filter( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: did you echo `$women_email` to check what are you getting?

Comment: adding echo in the function caused fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the contact form, it doesn't let you get the `$post->ID` of the parent post. This data is stored in the form's meta.  It's a hidden field passed in the form.

If you inspect your form from the front end, you'll see this For example:

`<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="2730">`

To get this, you access the `$submission->get_meta('$value')` method.

This will work for you, given that the `women_email` is properly formatted as an email address.  Also note that `before_send_mail` is an "ACTION" and not a "FILTER"

Below is not tested, but should work. Put this in functions.php

```
function wpcf7_before_send_mail_function($contact_form, &$abort, $submission){
    // This gets your post_id 
    $post_id = $submission->get_meta('container_post_id');
    $properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
    $properties['mail']['recipient'] = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'women_email', true);
    $contact_form->set_properties($properties);
}
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_before_send_mail_function', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 allows you to create an auto-responder, by selecting **Mail(2)**, which is located under the **Mail tab**.  You'll need to edit the relevant form:
[Contact Form 7 Mail Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEb86.png),
[Contact Form 7 Mail(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OprS.png).

You can then use your form's variable to populate the **"To"** field:
[Contact Form 7 auto-responder field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JkVE.png)

Comment: How does this insert a dynamic variable?

Comment: The original question states, _"I would like to send a confirmation email to a **dynamic recipient**."_  This functionality is baked into Contact Form 7. It's not necessary to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you're passing the post ID in correctly?
`get_the_ID()` needs [proper context](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/), in this case, the [WP Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)

I'm assuming this is a function in your functions.php.

```php
// Gets global $post object
global $post;

$email = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'women_email', true);
$properties = $contact_form->get_properties();
$properties['mail']['recipient'] = $email;
$contact_form->set_properties($properties);

return $contact_form;
```

This should do the trick.